# Add virtual NIC in CentOS docker container

Tags: docker, networking, centos, centos7, ifconfig

I'm trying to add a dummy network adapter to a docker container. I.e. not trying to connect to any actual interfaces on a local machine.

I've tried running `ifconfig` but to no avail:

`[root@240ae570546a /]# ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.10/24 up
SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFNETMASK: Operation not permitted`

I've also tried adding a configuration file to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` when building my docker container, but this doesn't seem to do the trick either.

My container is built on top of `centos:7`. How do I add a virtual NIC to my container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I needed to run the docker container with the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` command line param:

`docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it my_container /bin/bash`